# JOOQ - Select Distinct with Join - Fetch mapper

Tags: sql, kotlin, jooq

This is the SQL I am trying to create with JOOQ -

```sql
select distinct(kmp.*) from office_all_company_kmp kmp
 inner join company_kmp companykmp on kmp.id=companykmp.kmp_id
 where companykmp.company_id=?1
```

I am writing code in Kotlin. I had 2 issues doing this  -

1. In the select clause, unless I add a .asList() to the fields array, I couldn't get it compiling.
2. The fetch mapper had to be handcoded. Is there a way I can use do this without writing all that code? I can map records fetched back from one table without writing any mapping.

Here's what I am talking about:

```kotlin
fun OfficeAllCompanyKmpDao.findByCompany(companyId: UUID): List<OfficeAllCompanyKmp> =
    this.ctx()
        .selectDistinct(OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.fields().asList()) // without the asList() it wouldn't compile
        .from(OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP)
        .join(COMPANY_KMP).on(OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.ID.eq(COMPANY_KMP.KMP_ID))
        .where(COMPANY_KMP.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId))
        .fetch { // how do I write the mapper without manually writing code like the below?
            OfficeAllCompanyKmp(
                id = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.ID],
                officeId = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.OFFICE_ID],
                din = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.DIN],
                pan = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.PAN],
                name = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.NAME],
                dateOfBirth = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.DATE_OF_BIRTH],
                address = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.ADDRESS],
                email = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.EMAIL],
                kmpDetails = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.KMP_DETAILS],
                createdTimestamp = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.CREATED_TIMESTAMP],
                updatedTimestamp = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.UPDATED_TIMESTAMP],
                versionNo = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.VERSION_NO],
                createdUserId = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.CREATED_USER_ID],
                updatedUserId = it[OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.UPDATED_USER_ID]
            )
        }
```

Comment: 1) selectDistinct with OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.fields() works. What complier error do you get? 2) If OfficeAllCompanyKmp has a constructor with all the fields you retung then simply use fetchInto

Answer (score 1):

A better approach than inner joining and then removing duplicates again would be to semi join your other table using `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```kotlin
this.ctx()
    .selectFrom(OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP)
    .where(OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.ID.`in`(
         select(COMPANY_KMP.KMP_ID)
        .from(COMPANY_KMP)
        .where(COMPANY_KMP.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId)))
    .fetchInto(OfficeAllCompanyKmp::class.java)
```

Or, alternatively, use jOOQ's synthetic [`LEFT SEMI JOIN` syntax](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/join-clause/) ([see also this blog post for an explanation for this syntax](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/10/13/semi-join-and-anti-join-should-have-its-own-syntax-in-sql/), or [this one for joins in general](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/12/a-probably-incomplete-comprehensive-guide-to-the-many-different-ways-to-join-tables-in-sql/), or [Wikipedia's nice explanation about semi joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_(%E2%8B%89)(%E2%8B%8A)))

```kotlin
this.ctx()
    .select()
    .from(OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP)
    .leftSemiJoin(COMPANY_KMP)
    .on(OFFICE_ALL_COMPANY_KMP.ID.eq(COMPANY_KMP.KMP_ID))
    .and(COMPANY_KMP.COMPANY_ID.eq(companyId))
    .fetchInto(OfficeAllCompanyKmp::class.java)
```

Your problem 1) went away by using different jOOQ API, where you don't have to list all columns explicitly in `SELECT`. Your problem 2) is fixed easily by calling `fetchInto()` instead.